# Remove cached templates from ng-include in angular

Tags: angularjs, caching

how to remove caching from files that are used as templates in
 `ng-include="path/to/file.html"`

I tried to using `$templateCache.removeAll();`
but its not working

Is there any way we can clear cache in angular when the application loads?

Answer (score 1):

I had this trouble and I solved by adding a time parameter to a all URLs on my project, like path/to/file.html?t=4487664434
You can get the date ticks with the javascript funcion getTime(), from Date class.

Answer (score 0):

`$templateCache.removeAll()` *should* really work.

You could try running `$cacheFactory('templates').removeAll();` - but that is really what `$templateCache.removeAll()` is doing behind the scenes.

What does the surrounding implementation look like / in what context are you calling this method? Would it be possible for you to setup a plunker/fiddle for the case?